# Solution of an integral equation of the form $ \int_0^\infty K(r,z,t) f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = h(r,z) $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, indefinite-integrals, residue-calculus

I am looking for a way to solve the integral equations
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \operatorname{Re} \left\{ K(r,z,t) \right\}g_\pm(t) \, \mathrm{d} t 
&= h_\pm(r,z) \, , \\
\int_0^\infty \operatorname{Im} \left\{ K(r,z,t) \right\}f_\pm(t) \, \mathrm{d} t 
&= h_\pm(r,z) \, ,
\end{align}
wherein
$$
K(r,z,t) = \left( r^2 + (z-it)^2 \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}
$$
is the kernel function and the right-hand side is given by
$$
h_\pm(r,z) = \tfrac{\pi}{2} \left( r^2 + (z\pm 1)^2 \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \, .
$$

Here, $(r,z) \in \mathbb{R}_+^2$.
Using the method of residues, it can easily be shown that
$$
f_+(t) = \frac{t}{1+t^2} \, , \qquad
g_+(t) = \frac{1}{1+t^2} \, .
$$

However, the task seems to be more delicate for $f_-(t)$ and $g_-(t)$.
It would be great if someone could be of help and clarify how this problem can be tackled.

**Hint:**
it looks like applying Hankel transforms on both sides of the equations render the integral equations a bit simpler.